# Select query for Count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have one table in MySQL as below.

```
State marketId 
CA     Ind
CO     Ind
CA     Grp
CA     Grp
```

I want to select the data as count and Total of count(should be as below).

```
State marketId Count totalCountInd  totalCountGrp
  CA     Ind    1        2               2
  CO     Ind    1
  CA     Grp    2
```

Currently I am using below query. That is not giving the right output.

```
select state, marketId, count(*) as 'count', (select count(1) from BatchReport where marketId='Ind') as 'total' from  BatchReport group by state,marketId  having marketId='Ind'  
union  
select state, marketId, count(*) as 'count1', (select count(1) from BatchReport where marketId='Grp') as 'total1' from BatchReport group by state,marketId  having marketId='Grp'
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not a good (and ideal) way to retrieve data using SQL:

You are trying to retrieve two different records together. You should retrieve those with different queries:

First retrieve count for each state and marketId:

```
SELECT State, marketId, COUNT(marketId) AS Count
FROM BatchReport
GROUP BY State, marketID
```

Will give you

```
| STATE | MARKETID | COUNT(MARKETID) |
--------------------------------------
|    CA |      Grp |               2 |
|    CA |      Ind |               1 |
|    CO |      Ind |               1 |
```

Then retrieve total count for each marketId :

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE MarketID WHEN 'Ind' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd 
,SUM(CASE MarketID WHEN 'Grp' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountGrp
FROM BatchReport
```

Will give you

```
| TOTALCOUNTIND | TOTALCOUNTGRP |
---------------------------------
|             2 |             2 |
```

Or you can also get total count for each MarketId in rows like this:

```
SELECT
MarketId, COUNT(MarketID) AS Count
FROM BatchReport
GROUP BY MarketId;
```

Output:

```
| MARKETID | COUNT |
--------------------
|      Grp |     2 |
|      Ind |     2 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c9fb/14)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggetion.how can i combine both queries as single.

Comment: @hemachandra - What you want is not possible. Because you can not left other rows blank (from second rows). But [this type of query is possible](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c9fb/20).

Comment: @hemachandra - Did you get what I mean?

Comment: ya..got it...but my question here is like,how can i fetch two different select queries in DAO class as single list in java.
public List<SBCDocumentDetailsVO> getsBCDetails() throws DataAccessException, SQLException{
List<SBCDocumentDetailsVO> sbcDocList = new ArrayList<SBCDocumentDetailsVO>();


MapSqlParameterSource namedParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource();

//using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for querying
sbcDocList = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(
        sbcDetailsQuery, namedParameter,
        new sBCDetailsMapper());
return sbcDocList; }

Comment: @hemachandra That is another question. Always keep database layer and application layer separated. A database is there to get you the data, nothing more. Not for formatting issues, not to circumvent lack of programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT State, marketId, totalCount
    ,CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN (SELECT COUNT(marketId) FROM BatchReport WHERE marketId = 'Ind') END AS totalCountInd
    ,CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN (SELECT COUNT(marketId) FROM BatchReport WHERE marketId = 'Grp') END AS totalCountGrp 
FROM 
(
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rownum',B.* FROM
    (
      SELECT State, marketId, COUNT(marketId) AS totalCount
      FROM BatchReport
      GROUP BY State, marketID
    ) B, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r

) Result_BatchReport
```

**EDIT**

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c9fb/47)

Comment: dis query is not wrking..giving output like below.State | marketId | totalCount | totalCountInd | totalCountGrp
-------+----------+------------+---------------+---------------
 CA    | gr       |          2 |             0 |             0
 CA    | in       |          3 |          NULL |          NULL
 CO    | gr       |          3 |          NULL |          NULL
 CO    | in       |          2 |          NULL |          NULL
 CT    | gr       |          1 |          NULL |          NULL
 CT    | in       |          1 |          NULL |          NULL