# Suggest me query for count in MySql--I'm not getting proper output

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have one table in MySQL as below.

```
State marketId 
CA     Ind
CO     Ind
CA     Grp
CA     Grp
```

I want to select the data as count and Total of count(should be as below).

```
State marketId Count totalCountInd
  CA     Ind    1        2               
  CO     Ind    1
```

Currently I am using below query. That is not giving the right output.

```
select state,marketId,count(*),sum(CASE marketID WHEN 'ind' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountInd from BatchReport where marketId='ind' group by state,marketId;
+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
| state | marketId | count(*) | totalCountInd |
+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
| CA    | in       |        1 |               |
| CO    | in       |        1 |               |
|+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Is `totalCountInd` supposed to be the total count for all Ind markets through all States? If so, why do you want it to appear next to the state `CA`? If not, what do you want it to represent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select query for Count in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074729/select-query-for-count-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

this will give you a result closer to the one you want
the difference is it will repeat the totalCountInd

```
SELECT State, marketid, COUNT(1) as totalCount,
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BatchReport
    WHERE marketid = bp.marketid
) AS totalCountInd
FROM BatchReport bp
WHERE marketid = 'Ind'
GROUP BY State, marketid
```

the result is like:

```
State   marketid    totalCount  totalCountInd
CA      Ind         1           2
CO      Ind         1           2
```

Comment: helooo...i want totalCountInd column value is distinct something like this...State   marketid    totalCount  totalCountInd
CA      Ind         1           2
CO      Ind         1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the totalCOuntInd to hold the count of all states wit the marketId "Ind" then you cannot get this in your suggested format when grouping by state.

What you can do is use ROLLUP:

```
select state,marketId,count(*) as count
from BatchReport 
where marketId='ind' 
group by marketId, state with ROLLUP;
```

This will give you arollup result of all group columns and look like this:

```
marketId State Count
  Ind     CA    1                  
  Ind     CO    1
  Ind     NULL  2
  NULL    NULL  2
```

This is also the only way that makes sense.